# Hibernate different caches for different tables?

Tags: java, hibernate, infinispan, second-level-cache

In my project I have to put different table data to different L2 caches based on usage. Some tables require replicated cache while others can afford only distributed cache. Is this kind of configuration is possible with hibernate ?

In hibernate.properties we can only specify one cache

```
 hibernate.cache.infinispan.entity.cfg=replicated-cache-entity
 hibernate.cache.infinispan.collection.cfg=replicated-cache-entity
```

This cache is configured in ininispan.xml

```
   <namedCache name="replicated-cache-entity">
       <clustering mode="replication">
           <stateRetrieval fetchInMemoryState="false" timeout="20000"/>
           <sync replTimeout="20000"/>
       </clustering>
   </namedCache>
```

Is there a way to specify different caches ( cache names in infinispan ) for single table or class ?

OR

Is there a way to intercept hibernate L2 cache calls like infinispan interceptors ?

Answer (score 3):

The Infinispan [user guide](http://infinispan.org/docs/7.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_advanced_configuration_2) also mentions per-entity cache configurations:

> On top of that, this finer grained cache definition enables users to
>   define cache settings on a per entity/collection basis. For example:

```
<!-- If using Hibernate, add to your hibernate.cfg.xml --> 
<property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.com.acme.Person.cfg">   
  person-entity
</property> 
<property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.com.acme.Person.addresses.cfg">   
  addresses-collection
</property>
```

Comment: Indeed, this is the easiest way to achieve this. Just remember that the property name can vary when running in Wildfly or EAP. See docu.

Comment: Is this working if `com.acme.Person` is a sub class and related hbm is <subclass>. In my case I need to cache only one object in java inheritance tree but all this tree have only one table.